# Full automation for upgrading everything

Tags: upgrading

I have a Drupal 8.5.x site with the Redirect and the Metatag modules installed. I want to fully automate the process of upgrading Drupal including Drupal core, the translations, the themes, and any third-party module used on the site.
I want to upgrade the site from the Drupal UI, possibly without the need to create scripts.

Is it possible with Drupal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it *possible* to full upgrading with solely Drupal/PHP? In the sense that *anything* is possible given enough time/effort, yes.

Should you? Not unless you want to spend a lot of time building a bespoke, error-prone (especially if you're scoping in *any* modules, themes, etc.) process that will only work under the narrow scenario in which you developed it.

To get a sense of what you're asking, look at [auto updates initiative](https://www.drupal.org/project/ideas/issues/2940731). You're probably better off contributing/following the initiative instead of rolling your own.